# Bootstrap Installed and working fine but custom styling doesn't works

Tags: laravel, npm, bootstrap-4

I installed bootstrap and JavaScript through NPM in Laravel 6 and it's working fine since i am able to use bootstrap in my web page. But whenever i am adding custom styling in **resources/sass/app.scss** folder, the custom styling isn't works.

Comment: have you added(or loaded) custom styling before bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the app.scss file. Please run

> npm run dev

This will compile your scss file to public/css/app.css. Now you can link the css in your blade template as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" />
```